# Using return false is stopping my AJAX call from executing, removing it fixes it but then the page refreshes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery to AJAX POST a form and do not want the page to refresh. I have added return false command which prevents the page from refreshing but then the AJAX POST doesn't happen. If I remove the return false command, my AJAX POST is successful but the page refreshes. What am I doing wrong?

PHP code:

```
<form name="frmfeedback" id="frmfeedback" method="POST">
    <label>This answer was helpful</label>
    <input class="test" type="text" name="test" value=""/>
    <input class="hidden" id="fbackqueryval" type="text" name="fbackqueryval" value="1"/>
    <input class="btntick" type="submit" name="fbackresponse" value="Positive" onclick="submitdata()">
    <input class="btncross" type="submit" name="fbackresponse" value="Negative" onclick="submitdata()">
</form>
```

JS code:

```
function submitdata()
{
    $('#frmfeedback').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/",
            data: { fbackqueryval: "1"}
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved" );
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Remove button type='submit' or remove form tag and why you are defining event listener for form tag inside a function?

Comment: Change the button type submit to button . No need to return false in ajax because you are already using  e.preventDefault(). That will stop to refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks @LibinCJacob - this is correct but when I include code that stops the page from refreshing, my AJAX Post doesn't work. When I remove the page-refresh code, my AJAX works.

Comment: So your need is to refresh the page or not?

Comment: @LibinCJacob I want to submit my form using AJAX without a page refresh. I have now solved the issue and my completed answer is in the thread below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the comments combined eventually made the solution click.

Main learning points are:

1. Don't wrap the form elements in a  tag. I'll have to look into whether that breaks web standards and what happens when JS is not available but for the purposes of what I'm building, this is good enough
2. Because the code suggestions were fundamentally changing what and how I was posting data back to the server, this meant I had to adjust my PHP code for processing the incoming data. The reason it wasn't working for me is because I was looking for a POST value that I was no longer sending.

I haven't figured out how to create one function for dealing with the two different buttons so I have two functions linked to the two buttons: fbackPositive() and a fbackNegative().

JS code:

```
function fbackPositive() {
  $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "index.php",
          data: {
              fbackqueryval: "1",
              fbackresponse: "Positive"
          }
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
          alert("Data Saved");
      });

  return false;
}

function fbackNegative() {
  $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "index.php",
          data: {
              fbackqueryval: "1",
              fbackresponse: "Negative"
          }
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
          alert("Data Saved");
      });

  return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input class="" id="fbackqueryval" type="text" name="fbackqueryval" value="1"/>
<button class="btntick" type="button" name="fbackresponse" value="Positive" onclick="fbackPositive()">
<button class="btncross" type="button" name="fbackresponse" value="Negative" onclick="fbackNegative()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three ways to do this.

*First way*
Stop the `submitdata` returning false (remove it from `done` callback)

```
function submitdata() {
    $('#frmfeedback').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/",
                data: {
                    fbackqueryval: "1"
                }
            })
            .done(function(msg) {
                alert("Data Saved");
            });
    });
    return false;
}
```

*Second way*
Change type button to `type=button` instead of `type=submit`

```
<input class="btntick" type="button" name="fbackresponse" value="Positive" onclick="submitdata()">
<input class="btncross" type="button" name="fbackresponse" value="Negative" onclick="submitdata()">
```

*Third way*
Add return false to `onClick` attribute:

```
<input class="btntick" type="submit" name="fbackresponse" value="Positive" onclick="submitdata();return false;">
<input class="btncross" type="submit" name="fbackresponse" value="Negative" onclick="submitdata();return false;">
```

As mentioned by others, you are making a double-call to your route `/`

You can do it as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=button][name=fbackresponse]').on('click', function(e) {
        fbackqueryval = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/",
            data: {
                fbackqueryval: fbackqueryval
            }
        })
        .done(function(msg) {
            alert("Data Saved");
        });
    });
});

<input class="btntick" type="button" name="fbackresponse" value="1">
<input class="btncross" type="button" name="fbackresponse" value="-1">
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your last example in JSFiddle but it didn't work? https://jsfiddle.net/8hbckknL/

Comment: This becouse `$this` need to be `$(this)`. My mistake

Answer (score 1):

It is refreshing the page, because you are submitting the form.

> if you want to make an AJAX-Call, you do not need to submit a form.

Just change your code like below:

JQuery:

```
  $('.myAjaxButton').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/myAjax.php",
        data: { fbackqueryval: "1"}
      })
      .done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved" );
      });
  });
```

and html:

```
    <label>This answer was helpful</label>
    <button class="btntick myAjaxButton">Positive</button>
    <button class="btncross myAjaxButton">Negative</button>
```

You can check: https://jsfiddle.net/32dLa1wh/

If it doesn't work for you, you should debug your php file (in example myAjax.php)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but using your example as-is resulted in a page refresh and the AJAX post didn't work (pop up message didn't appear and DB record didn't get saved).

Comment: Does the version of jQuery I'm using make a difference? I'm using jquery-3.2.1.min

Comment: should not make a difference, let me write a working example for you and link with jsfiddle :)

Comment: I've added your sample to jsfiddle but it doesn't seem to be running for me https://jsfiddle.net/4k6cessq/#&togetherjs=VTvlFgDIDA

Comment: Thanks, eventually got there. I've posted my definitive completed answer which has worked. You were right to point me to my PHP file to look into why it wasn't working and it's down to the fact that I was fundamentally changing how I was posting the data to the server vs. how it was expected before adding JS AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `button type`

```
<input class="btntick" type="button" name="fbackresponse" value="Positive" onclick="submitdata()">
<input class="btncross" type="button" name="fbackresponse" value="Negative" onclick="submitdata()">
```

Answer (score 0):

The return must be outside the done-callback.
So submitdata must return false to stop the submit-event.

Changing the type of the buttons will not fix the problem when the user press enter inside a input field.